# Adding React Native module doesn't add line to Podfile, but `pod install` installs it anyway

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podfile, react-native-device-info

I added [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) with `npm i react-native-device-info`. I'm using React Native 0.61, so I expected that it would automatically add a line in my Podfile for RNDeviceInfo. My Podfile didn't change, BUT when I ran `pod install`, it said "Installing React Native Device Info". I notice that doing this didn't add a `.xcodeproj` or `.a` file to Xcode.
Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go node_modules folder, and find react-native-device-info folder and final step is remove RNDeviceInfo.podspec file. I recommended you copy RNDeviceInfo.podspec file before removing.